# OSGi plug-in gets remove after reboot

Tags: osgi, equinox, kura

I have created 3 different OSGI plugins (developed as an Eclipse Plugin project) running inside Eclipse Kura on a Raspberry PI. Two plugins are behaving as a library providing classed used in common. The third plugin is a service communicating with the serial port using the mechanisms provided by Kura. The latter has been developed as described on the Kura getting started pages. The two library plugins are basic plugin projects.

Everything is resolved and started correctly and seems to work as expected, so nothing special about that. Problems appear when the PI is rebooted, causing off course the OSGI engine to restart as well. The two library plugins seems to be removed by the reboot. The serial communication service is still present but fails to start due to missing dependencies.

My question is: what causes the plugins to be removed on reboot and how does one prevent this of happening? Thanks for reading this post!

Comment: How did you add the bundles?

Comment: I installed the bundle using the install command at the OSGI prompt (install file://... in which the JAR file is passed) instead of the Kura console. Currently I created a workaround by adding a dummy class in the bundle with a activate/deactivate method doing nothing. This class is referenced as an OSGi service using a component descriptor file (component.xml). This allows the bundle to be packed as a DP-file and deployed using the Kura console. Now the bundle remains installed after reboot. Although this works, I think better solutions might exist as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you export your bundles as OSGi Deployment Package.
Then copy the DP in your Pi and tell Kura to load it at startup.

I wrote a [sample project](https://github.com/darugnaa/deployment-package-example) that you can use to create the the Deployment Package with Maven, or you can package your bundles with a bash script.

After the packaging, copy your DP into **/opt/eclipse/kura/kura/packages/** folder.
Then edit the **/opt/eclipse/kura/kura/dpa.properties** file and add a line for your DP

```
yourbundles=file\:/opt/eclipse/kura/kura/packages/your-bundles.dp
```

[This is the official Kura documentation on how to do it](https://eclipse.github.io/kura/doc/deploying-bundles.html#making-deployment-permanent).

Alternatives would be to either install the DP using Kura's web UI or the [DEPLOY](https://github.com/eclipse/kura/blob/69ca4b64000ab1328dd5e99122833190ef3856fa/kura/org.eclipse.kura.core.deployment/src/main/java/org/eclipse/kura/core/deployment/CloudDeploymentHandlerV2.java) cloudlet.

Comment: First of all happy new year and thanks for your reply! So if I understand correctly, using the web UI automatically updates Kura to load OSGi bundles on startup as long as they are deployment packages. So it would be possible to create a deployment package without the "dummy" component definition inside I'm currently using as a workaround. Behavior is different when a JAR is deployed using the CLI.

Comment: @KDW Yes. Kura automatically adds the entry to **dpa.properties** file when you upload a DP in web ui. The DP, which may contain more than one bundle, will be reloaded at next startups.

Comment: @Neil I marked the solution presented by Alessandro as the answer to the question since it has the advantage not having to change the default configuration of the OSGi engine included in Kura allthough I appreciate your solution as well. To bad for both my reputation does not allow me to upvote answers. Thanks for both responses.

Answer (score 0):

As you state in your clarification, the `install` command is used to add the dependency bundles. OSGi is normally persistent, so that if you install bundles in any way (including with the `install` command) they will still be present and in the same state when you next start OSGi.

In order for this to work, OSGi has a "storage" folder. This is configured by setting the `org.osgi.framework.storage` property, which in Equinox defaults to `./configuration`. It's possible that your launcher clears out this directory, therefore causing OSGi to lose its persistent state.

There are two potential solutions:

1. Don't clear the OSGi storage folder.
2. Configure your launcher application to always include all the bundles that you want.

I would actually recommend doing both. OSGi is *meant* to be persistent; but also it's not really user-friendly to require a user to type `install` commands in order to make an application work.

Comment: Also first of all a happy new year as well. Using the approach of the install command and a "normal" (meaning a non deployment package bundled bundle) should work as well as long as the launcher does not clear the storage folder.